# How to encode empty transaction fields?

Tags: transactions, addresses, raw-transaction, encoding, rlp

I want to RLP-encode a(n unsigned) transaction. Some fields of the transaction can be empty/null/zero. I want to know how they are encoded, though.

Let's assume the following transaction fields:

```ruby
signer_nonce = 0
gas_price = 0
gas_limit = 21000
destination = nil
amount = 0
payload = nil
```

Nonce, gas price, limit, and amount are easily encoded using any RLP-encoder and a value of `0x00` is perfectly fine.

But how do I encode empty fields if I don't have any data or any recipient address?

```ruby
Eth::Util.bin_to_hex(RLP.encode(nil))
/home/user/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rlp-0.7.3/lib/rlp/sedes.rb:31:in `infer': Did not find sedes handling type NilClass (TypeError)
    from /home/user/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rlp-0.7.3/lib/rlp/encode.rb:51:in `encode'
    from (irb):14:in `<main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /bin/irb:23:in `load'
    from /bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
```

I cannot set the address to `0x00` as this would be a valid address afaik. Should I use the empty string byte `0x80`? How would I distinguish and empty string from the zero byte `0x80`?

```ruby
Eth::Util.bin_to_hex(RLP.encode(""))
=> "80"
Eth::Util.bin_to_hex(RLP.encode(0))
=> "80"
```

How to encode empty transaction fields such as empty data or no recipient address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these field have to be provided and should not be `nil`. There are generally 2 different types when encoding a transaction with RLP: 256-bit Number and a Bytes.

So if we have an empty `data` we would encode it as an empty bytes (e.g. `0x`). In this case an empty string and an empty bytes are the same, as a string would be converted to bytes before RLP encoding.

For the address it is a little bit more tricky. It is defined as a Bytes that has a length of 20. Unless you have a creation transaction then it is an empty bytes.

You can find an example how this is implemented in the Kethereum repositors:

- [RLP Encoding](https://github.com/komputing/KEthereum/blob/253239841cc71d824d77c6cd8c1abcb655cc2cd8/extensions_transactions/src/main/kotlin/org/kethereum/extensions/transactions/TransactionRLPEncoder.kt#L12)
- [Type Mapping](https://github.com/komputing/KEthereum/blob/master/rlp/src/main/kotlin/org/kethereum/rlp/RLPTypeConverter.kt)

You can find the more formal definition in the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) at the beginning of page 5.

A list of all fields that should be encoded in a Transaction can for example be found in [EIP-1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559#specification) for the latest format.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm implementing EIP-1559, hence the question. Using the empty byte apparently works! :)