# How exactly is the signature encoded in a raw transaction?

Tags: signature, ecdsa

I'm working on an Ethereum wallet as part of a school project. I am currently trying to sign this example transaction: `0xec098504a817c800825208943535353535353535353535353535353535353535880de0b6b3a764000080018080`.

This is my code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import keccak
import rlp
import codecs
import ecdsa

# my ethereum address
addr = "0x1d67D36D8f7c2BBB600DE227E564f0cA5925544F"

# my private key (don't worry, it's just for testing)
pk_bytes = codecs.decode('23a3f8b9e35cc26bb70306ab313bcbbd3804e9d18bcb2f51a9b137bb8fe543e5', 'hex_codec')
sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(pk_bytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)

# the data i want to sign
rlp_bytes = codecs.decode('ec098504a817c800825208943535353535353535353535353535353535353535880de0b6b3a764000080018080', 'hex_codec')

# keccak hashing the data
k = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
k.update(rlp_bytes)
txHash = k.digest()

# getting the signature
sig = sk.sign(txHash)

# extracting r and s
r = int(sig[:32].hex(), 16)
s = int(sig[32:].hex(), 16)

# eip-2: If s is larger than secp256k1n / 2, set s = -s % secp256k1n
secp256k1n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
if s > secp256k1n / 2:
    s = secp256k1n - s
    v = 35 + 1 * 2 + 1  # mainnet chain id = 1
else:
    v = 35 + 1 * 2 + 0

# build signed transaction
signedTx = rlp.decode(rlp_bytes)
signedTx[6] = v.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
signedTx[7] = r.to_bytes(32, byteorder='big')
signedTx[8] = s.to_bytes(32, byteorder='big')

# rlp encode to get raw transaction
signedTxEncoded = rlp.encode(signedTx)
print("Raw transaction: 0x" + codecs.encode(signedTxEncoded, 'hex_codec').decode())
```

When we use [an online tool](https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum#transaction) to decode the resulting transactions (such as `0xf86c098504a817c800825208943535353535353535353535353535353535353535880de0b6b3a7640000802da00d5f27bbc8b38f04523f26f4e86e18e8b61126a55c23b11e615266a02017b8afa06193f48e5925fc9cbfdc8b0f651b3c8a118a0bd0054766522211cf819bc11b75`), the tool displays an incorrect sender address. If I attempt to submit it to the blockchain, the transaction is rejected due to "insufficient funds" (because the random sender address doesn't own any eth). Since we're using a library for the ECDSA signing, we believe the issue might be with data formatting.

What am I doing wrong?

(I am not looking for recommendations of web3 or other Ethereum libraries; I have to do this the "hard" way).

Comment: Perhaps this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117384/how-to-encode-empty-transaction-fields has some links to the possible problem.